# DMax Number Sequence Fix Gap

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this function to where it tries to auto sequence a number starting at the number 8000 and the number seeds back to 8000 every day. The function also attempts to ensure that there is no gap so if there is a manual entry and the number creates a gap the field will not sequence from the manual entry. But I cannot seem to get the code to work as it just stays at the same number from the previous entry and does not increase.

```
Public Function fRetNextInSequence() As Long
 Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
 Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
 Dim rstClone As DAO.Recordset

 'If there are no Records in tblData, then have the Function return 8000
 If DCount("strSerialNumber", "tblOrderData", "dtmDateOrdered=#" & Date & "#") = 0 Then
   fRetNextInSequence = 8000
     Exit Function
End If

 Set MyDB = CurrentDb
 Set rst = MyDB.OpenRecordset("tblOrderData", dbOpenSnapshot)
 Set rstClone = rst.Clone

 rst.MoveLast        'Move to Last Record [MyNum]
 With rstClone       'Move to Next-to-Last Record [MyNum]
   .MoveLast
   .Move -1          'Clone now at Next-to-Last Record [MyNum]
 End With

 With rst
   Do While Not rstClone.BOF
     If Abs(![strSerialNumber] - rstClone![strSerialNumber]) > 1 Then
       fRetNextInSequence = (rstClone![strSerialNumber] + 1)       'Found the Gap!
         Exit Function
     End If
       .MovePrevious             'Move in sync, 1 Record apart
       rstClone.MovePrevious
   Loop
 End With

 rst.MoveLast

 fRetNextInSequence = (rst![strSerialNumber] + 1)       'No Gap found, return next number in sequence!

 rstClone.Close
 rst.Close
 Set rstClone = Nothing
 Set rst = Nothing
 End Function       

    If SOS = "ES-S" Then
        SerialNbrValue = fRetNextInSequence
        'SerialNbrValue = Val(Nz(DMax("strSerialNumber", "tblOrderData", "dtmDateOrdered=#" & Date & "#"), 7999)) + 1
    Else
        SerialNbrValue = ""
    End If
```

Comment: Why do you show code outside a procedure? That `If SOS ...` should cause compile error.

Answer (score 0):

Exiting the function from the loop bypasses the lines to close and clear the recordset objects. That isn't causing the issue but why have them if they aren't used everytime the recordsets are opened?

The following revised procedure worked for me to return appropriate sequence when I call the function from the VBA Immediate Window:

```
Public Function fRetNextInSequence() As Long
Dim MyDB As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim rstClone As DAO.Recordset

If Nz(DMin("strSerialNumber", "tblOrderData", "dtmDateOrdered=Date()"), 0) <> 8000 Then
    'If there are no Records or the gap is 8000 for current date, Function returns 8000
    fRetNextInSequence = 8000
Else
    Set MyDB = CurrentDb
    Set rst = MyDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT strSerialNumber FROM tblOrderData WHERE dtmDateOrdered=Date() ORDER BY strSerialNumber", dbOpenSnapshot)
    Set rstClone = rst.Clone

    rst.MoveLast        'Move to Last Record [MyNum]
    With rstClone       'Move to Next-to-Last Record [MyNum]
      .MoveLast
      .Move -1          'Clone now at Next-to-Last Record [MyNum]
    End With

    With rst
    Do While Not rstClone.BOF
        If Abs(![strSerialNumber] - rstClone![strSerialNumber]) > 1 Then
            'Found the Gap!
            fRetNextInSequence = (rstClone![strSerialNumber] + 1)
            Exit Do
        End If
        .MovePrevious             'Move in sync, 1 Record apart
        rstClone.MovePrevious
    Loop
    End With

    If fRetNextInSequence = 0 Then
        'No Gap found, return next number in sequence!
        rst.MoveLast
        fRetNextInSequence = (rst![strSerialNumber] + 1)       
    End If
    rstClone.Close
    rst.Close
    Set rstClone = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
End If
End Function
```